# Include datetime.now

Tags: asp.net, datetime, insert

I have a sign up page, when the user clicked the submit button, the data from the registration form will be stored in database. I also need to insert the date when the user created the account. How can include 'datetime.now' in my insert query...

Below is my code:

```
private void ExecuteInsert(string streetAdr, string city, string state, int countryID, string zipCode, string TelNum, string FaxNum)
    {
        SqlConnection connectionString = new SqlConnection(GetConnectString());
        try
        {
            connectionString.Open();

            // Insert Address
            string addressQuery = "Insert into Address (StreetAdd, City, State, CountryID, ZipCode, TelNum, FaxNum)" +
                              "VALUES (@stAd, @CityAdr, @StateAdr, @IDcountry, @zCode ,@Tnumb ,@Fnumb)";

            SqlCommand addressCmd = new SqlCommand(addressQuery, connectionString);
            SqlParameter[] address = new SqlParameter[7];

            address[0] = new SqlParameter("@stAd", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
            address[1] = new SqlParameter("@CityAdr", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
            address[2] = new SqlParameter("@StateAdr", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
            address[3] = new SqlParameter("@IDcountry", SqlDbType.Int, 100);
            address[4] = new SqlParameter("@zCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
            address[5] = new SqlParameter("@Tnumb", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
            address[6] = new SqlParameter("@Fnumb", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);

            address[0].Value = streetAdr;
            address[1].Value = city;
            address[2].Value = state;
            address[3].Value = countryID;
            address[4].Value = zipCode;
            address[5].Value = TelNum;
            address[6].Value = FaxNum;

            for (int i = 0; i < address.Length; i++)
            {
                addressCmd.Parameters.Add(address[i]);
            }
            addressCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            addressCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 

        }
        finally 
        {
            connectionString.Close();
        }
    }
```

where should put datetime.now? thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a date column in your database and either pass it the date as a parameter as you have with the other fields above,or give the field a default value in the database.

```
private void ExecuteInsert(string streetAdr, string city, string state, int countryID, string zipCode, string TelNum, string FaxNum)
    {
        SqlConnection connectionString = new SqlConnection(GetConnectString());
        try
        {
            connectionString.Open();

        // Insert Address
        string addressQuery = "Insert into Address (StreetAdd, City, State, CountryID, ZipCode, TelNum, FaxNum, TransactioNDate)" +
                          "VALUES (@stAd, @CityAdr, @StateAdr, @IDcountry, @zCode ,@Tnumb ,@Fnumb, @Date)";

        SqlCommand addressCmd = new SqlCommand(addressQuery, connectionString);
        SqlParameter[] address = new SqlParameter[8];

        address[0] = new SqlParameter("@stAd", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        address[1] = new SqlParameter("@CityAdr", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        address[2] = new SqlParameter("@StateAdr", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        address[3] = new SqlParameter("@IDcountry", SqlDbType.Int, 100);
        address[4] = new SqlParameter("@zCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        address[5] = new SqlParameter("@Tnumb", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        address[6] = new SqlParameter("@Fnumb", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        address[7] = new SqlParameter("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime);

        address[0].Value = streetAdr;
        address[1].Value = city;
        address[2].Value = state;
        address[3].Value = countryID;
        address[4].Value = zipCode;
        address[5].Value = TelNum;
        address[6].Value = FaxNum;
        address[7].Value = DateTime.Now();

        for (int i = 0; i < address.Length; i++)
        {
            addressCmd.Parameters.Add(address[i]);
        }
        addressCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        addressCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 

    }
    finally 
    {
        connectionString.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, i have a field for the date..so i need to declare datetime in my parameter....then how will i include in the insert query.. #___#
@ DavidB

Comment: PS, you shouldnt be catching the exceptionw ithout handlinG it, how will you know when something has gone wrong?

Comment: the dateTime is now working..
but I have another question..

for example..when a merchant is finished with the sign up form, the inputs from the form will be saved in different tables..
in my form there will are two tables involved...(1) address -> this is where the address of the merchant will be saved.. and (2) merchant_master -> this has a addrID field..instead of the address ( address, city, state, country) will be saved here the id of the address from dbo.address will be saved here...how will i do that..? @davidB